# Stripping all '\n' from HTMLCalendar()

Tags: python, calendar

```
import calendar

def websiteCalendar(month, year):
    return calendar.HTMLCalendar().formatmonth(year, month).rstrip("\n")
```

returns:

```
"<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" class=\"month\">\n<tr><th colspan=\"7\" class=\"month\">November 2016</th></tr>\n<tr><th class=\"mon\">Mon</th><th class=\"tue\">Tue</th><th class=\"wed\">Wed</th><th class=\"thu\">Thu</th><th class=\"fri\">Fri</th><th class=\"sat\">Sat</th><th class=\"sun\">Sun</th></tr>\n<tr><td class=\"noday\">&nbsp;</td><td class=\"tue\">1</td><td class=\"wed\">2</td><td class=\"thu\">3</td><td class=\"fri\">4</td><td class=\"sat\">5</td><td class=\"sun\">6</td></tr>\n<tr><td class=\"mon\">7</td><td class=\"tue\">8</td><td class=\"wed\">9</td><td class=\"thu\">10</td><td class=\"fri\">11</td><td class=\"sat\">12</td><td class=\"sun\">13</td></tr>\n<tr><td class=\"mon\">14</td><td class=\"tue\">15</td><td class=\"wed\">16</td><td class=\"thu\">17</td><td class=\"fri\">18</td><td class=\"sat\">19</td><td class=\"sun\">20</td></tr>\n<tr><td class=\"mon\">21</td><td class=\"tue\">22</td><td class=\"wed\">23</td><td class=\"thu\">24</td><td class=\"fri\">25</td><td class=\"sat\">26</td><td class=\"sun\">27</td></tr>\n<tr><td class=\"mon\">28</td><td class=\"tue\">29</td><td class=\"wed\">30</td><td class=\"noday\">&nbsp;</td><td class=\"noday\">&nbsp;</td><td class=\"noday\">&nbsp;</td><td class=\"noday\">&nbsp;</td></tr>\n</table>"
```

For some reason it keeps '\n', is there an easy way to strip out all the '\n' from the returned text? I successfully stripped the '\n' element at the end, but there is still the one before the  tag that I can't seem to get rid of.

Comment: `str.replace()` sounds good for this job, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just to remove all `'\n'` occurrences from string you should try

```
calendar.HTMLCalendar().formatmonth(year, month).replace("\n", "")
```

Comment: sometimes I think I' the dumbest human being on the planet. [I will accept this as correct when stackoverflow lets me]